# "Unpacking" in C

Tags: python, c, unpack, iterable-unpacking

I am working on rewriting a script from **python** to **C**. I'm relatively new to C.

I have a variable in PYTHON which contains this values:

```
x = [chr(113),chr(80),chr(191),chr(70)]

y = "".join(x)
```

This will return this value of y:

```
y = qP¿F           #this is string
```

Now what I do is unpack this variable, store it to variable *z* to get the results that I wanted. Like this:

```
z = struct.unpack("<f",y)
print z[0]  #unpack returns a tuple of size 1
```

The value that I get is:

```
x = 24488.2207
```

which for my case is correct.

I was wondering if there is a same function in **C** that I can use for this?

Comment: you just cast the bytes to a float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for such a function; provided the endianness is already correct the compiler can handle that case itself either through pointer casting or through a `union` type.

```
uint8_t data[4] = {113, 80, 191, 70};

printf("%f\n", (double)(*(float*)data));
```

...

```
$ ./a.out 
24488.220703
```

Comment: Indeed, if it wasn't so easy in C then other languages wouldn't need to provide libraries to emulate it.