# Interpret data from Modbus ASCII in C

Tags: python, c, ascii, modbus

I have a reply from a MODBUS ASCII protocol device.

I store the "data" part of the reply into an array in C:

```
char test_reply[10];
char buffer[255]; //contains all the reply from modbus device following ascii protocol
```

`//store the "data part" of the reply to test_reply to fix endianness`

```
test_reply[0] = buffer[9];
test_reply[1] = buffer[10];
test_reply[2] = buffer[7];
test_reply[3] = buffer[8];
test_reply[4] = buffer[13];
test_reply[5] = buffer[14];
test_reply[6] = buffer[11];
test_reply[7] = buffer[12];
```

I print this one and I got:

```
printf("this is the data reply: %s\n", test_reply)
"this is the data reply: 7B346543"
```

If I get the length of the string, I'm getting 8 (which I think is correct).

I believe each of those characters can be interpreted like this:

char(0x37) = 7

char(0x42) = B

char(0x33) = 3

and so on...

Now, I have to get a value of "229.20" from the reply.

What I do is manually input them to a variable and compute using a command in python.

like this:

```
>> x = chr(0x7B) + chr(0x34) + chr(0x65) +chr(0x43)
>> y = "".join(x)
>> z = struct.unpack("<f",y)
>> print z
(229.2050,)
```

I believe the way you do it in C is like on my previous post:
[Unpacking in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937988/unpacking-in-c)

I want to ask if there is a way to do the other one in C

Comment: I already did strtod but I'm getting a 0,000 values.

Comment: Probably you are storing data in the wrong way, before to call strtod. Post your code.

Comment: `char *ptr;

double val;


val = strtod(test_reply, &ptr);

printf("value: %f\n", val);`

Comment: I meant the code that store data into `test_reply` array. Do not post code in comments, edit your question.

Comment: In your `printf` after the `strtod` use `%lf` since you are creating a double, not a float (they are the same in Python, but not in C)

Comment: @cdarke `printf` always promotes `float` to `double`. `%f` is ok.

Comment: After `test_reply[7] = buffer[12];` make sure there is an ASCII NUL to terminate the string:  `test_reply[8] = 0;` before doing any kind of string operation on it, including `strtod()`, `strlen()`, `printf ("%s")`, etc.  Otherwise, garbage characters from the uninitialized array elements may cause trouble.

Comment: Thanks. I got how the strtod works and I think its not what I'm looking for

Comment: Not necessarily anything to do with your problem, but did you really mean `chr(43)` and not `chr(0x43)`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No. I mean chr(0x43). thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: the functions that begin with `str` must be passed a NUL terminated string.  which the code you presented does not append the NUL byte.  So any returned value is trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need is a way to convert the 2 bytes sequence `"7B"` of `{ 0x37, 0x42 }` to the single byte `0x7b`.

`sscanf` with a `x` format is what you need. Assuming you know you have only 8 useful characters in test_reply, that you have already dealt with endianness on your platform and want to store them in a 32 bits float, you can do:

```
int i;
float z;
unsigned char *ix = (unsigned char *) &z; // you can always convert any address to a char *

for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    sscanf(test_reply + 2 * i, "%2hhx", &ix[i]); // 2 to process only 2 chars, hh to store only one byte
}

// control:
printf("%f\n", z);  // should output 229.205002
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving from ModBus ASCII value of the HEX representation of float 229,20. You must convert they manually like in the following example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t getDigit ( uint8_t digit)
{
    uint8_t retVal = 0;

    if ((digit >= '0') && (digit <= '9'))
    {
       retVal = digit -  '0';
    }
    else if ((digit >= 'A') && (digit <= 'F'))
    {
       retVal = digit - 'A' + 10;
    }
    else if ((digit >= 'a') && (digit <= 'f'))
    {
       retVal = digit - 'a' + 10;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong char\n");
    }

    return retVal;
}

uint8_t ascii2bin (uint8_t hi, uint8_t lo)
{
    uint8_t retVal = (getDigit(hi) << 4) | getDigit(lo);

    return retVal;
}

int main()
{
    char *ModBus_value = "33336543";
    float yourFloatData;
    char *special_ptr = (char *)(&yourFloatData);
    int i;
    int len = strlen(ModBus_value);

    if ( len == (sizeof(float)*2) )
    {
        for (i=0; i<len; i+=2)
        {
            *special_ptr = ascii2bin(ModBus_value[i], ModBus_value[i+1]);
            special_ptr++;
        }

        printf("yourFloatData_1: %f\n", yourFloatData );
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong string\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Other implementation, less readale of getDigit should be:

```
uint8_t getDigit ( uint8_t digit)
{
    uint8_t retVal = 0;

    if ((digit >= '0') && (digit <= '9'))
    {
        retVal = digit -  '0';
    }
    else if ((digit >= 'A') && (digit <= 'F'))
    {
        retVal = digit - '7';
    }
    else if ((digit >= 'a') && (digit <= 'f'))
    {
        retVal = digit - 'W';
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong char\n");
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Or

```
uint8_t getDigit ( uint8_t digit)
{
    uint8_t retVal = 0;

    if ((digit >= '0') && (digit <= '9'))
    {
        retVal = digit -  '0';
    }
    else if ((digit >= 'A') && (digit <= 'F'))
    {
        retVal = digit - 55;
    }
    else if ((digit >= 'a') && (digit <= 'f'))
    {
        retVal = digit - 87;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong char\n");
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Or

```
uint8_t getDigit ( uint8_t digit)
{
    uint8_t retVal = 0;

    if ((digit >= '0') && (digit <= '9'))
    {
        retVal = digit -  '0';
    }
    else if ((digit >= 'A') && (digit <= 'F'))
    {
        retVal = digit - 55;
    }
    else if ((digit >= 'a') && (digit <= 'f'))
    {
        retVal = digit - 87;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong char\n");
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, Is your `*ModBus_value` my `test_reply`?

Comment: @EnzoVidal Yes, it is. NULL terminated.